# How to fetch all nested markdown files in Nuxt content?

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I'm trying to fetch for each A, B, C category a different folder in my content folder.

The best way I've managed to do that is using `v-for` and some arrays list in order to have my category list at the same place.
This array works with `slots` that generate a new `Item` for each new element:

```html
 <div v-for="accordion in accordions" :key="accordion.title" class="l">
      <Item>
        <template #title>
          {{ accordion.title }}
        </template>

        <template #content>
          <div>{{ accordion.text }}</div>
        </template>
      </Item>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have this to fetch my articles:

```js
  async asyncData ({ $content }) {
    const articles = await $content('', { deep: true })
      .only(['title', 'description', 'img', 'slug', 'cat'])
      .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .fetch()

    return { articles }
  }, // this fetch all of my articles, which is nice
```

Now, in the accordions, I would like to do something similar to this:
(or find a way to pass a `.where({ cat: 'A' })`...)

```js
 accordions: [
        {
          title: 'A',
          text: const products = await this.$content('text').where({ 'articles.cat': { $contains: 'A' } }).fetch()
        },
        {
          title: 'B',
          text: const products = await this.$content('text').where({ 'articles.cat': { $contains: 'B' } }).fetch()
        },
        {
          title: 'C',
          text: const products = await this.$content('text').where({ 'articles.cat': { $contains: 'C' } }).fetch()
        }
      ],
```

[image]

How can I manage to instead of hardcoded text, have my articles from my content folder?

[image: Supposed render]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives a nice result (with some random `.md` files but the same structure as yours).

```html
<template>
  <pre>{{ articles }}</pre>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData ({ $content }) {
    const articles = await $content('', { deep: true })
      .only(['title', 'description', 'img', 'slug'])
      .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
      .fetch()

    return { articles }
  }
}
</script>
```

Official source: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/750#issuecomment-774495039

The result displayed being

[image]

Comment: This works as intented as it displays a list of all my posts, which is nice.
I've made an edit to my original post in order to clarify what I was trying to make!